# How to revert all files in directory to older SVN version

Tags: svn

I want to revert the SVN files on my computer only to an older version. I don't want to commit the changes to the repository.

I tried `svn merge -rCurrentVersion:revertToVersion`, but I get:

```
[root]# svn merge -r150:139
svn: Try 'svn help' for more info
svn: Merge source required
```

How do I do this?

Comment: If your goal is to get rid of all local changes and sync back to a specific version then there's always the option of just deleting the local tree and re-downloading from the repository.

Comment: No. The goal is to get rid of the changes from the last few "svn up"s, and revert back to an older version on my local machine only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`svn update`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.update.html) command with the [`--revision`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.revision) flag.

```
svn update -r 139
```

Comment: if you don't like typing, "up" is shorthand for update: `svn up -r 139`